# About error Error Code: 1872. Coordinator stopped because there were error(s) in the buffer_pool_size (s) RDS MYSQL 5.7

Tags: mysql-5.7, amazon-rds

My replication  instance is a read replica in rds Amazon, with those configurations

```
select @@innodb_buffer_pool_size;
99857989632
SELECT @@innodb_buffer_pool_instances;
8
SELECT @@innodb_buffer_pool_chunk_size ;
134217728
```

And I saw too in the parameter file in the RDS parameter group with values

```
innodb_buffer_pool_instances    -
innodb_buffer_pool_chunk_size   -
innodb_buffer_pool_size {DBInstanceClassMemory*3/4}
```

My question is.
What wrong is with my configuration? Because I never saw those errors in two years in this client.